# Django: Using decorators on methods in a subclass to handle requests from urls.py

Tags: python, django, class, model-view-controller

I used to have some massive files with decorated funtions called from `urls.py`. This wasn't sustainable so they were split into controllers, with logic somewhere else (not relevant for this question). The controllers are subclassed from a main `Controller` class to share frequent imports and other commonalities.
I can't get the decorator functions to work now, the closest I've gotten are

```
AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `api.controllers.FooController.FooController`.
```

and

```
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Neither using a `get()` with `as_view()` nor a custom method work, as seen below.
I've tried `@method_decorator(login_required)` etc. with no success.
My files (simplified) are below. Do not mind the method contents, this is just for demonstration.

`api/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from api.controllers.FooController import FooController
urlpatterns = [
    path("get_foo", FooController,as_view(), name="get_foo")
    path("get_bar", FooController.foo_bar, name="get_bar")
]
```

`api/controllers/Controller.py`:

```
from django.views import View
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse, StreamingHttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class Controller(View):
    def __init__(self):
        # Set some variables
    # define some methods
```

`api/controllers/FooController.py`:

```
from api.controllers.Controller import *

class FooController(Controller):
    method_decorator(api_view(["GET"]))
    method_decorator(login_required)
    method_decorator(authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication,)))
    method_decorator(permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,)))
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=401)

    method_decorator(api_view(["GET"]))
    method_decorator(login_required)
    method_decorator(authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication,)))
    method_decorator(permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,)))
    def foo_bar(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return JsonResponse({"data": "some data"}, status=200)
```

Thanks so much in advance if anyone can help me with this!

Comment: I don't know why you're writing your own wrapper class, for function-based views that implement what DRF calls [Generic Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/), [viewsets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) and [routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `urls.py`, use paths like so:

```
path("get_foo", FooController.as_view({"get":"get_foo"}), name="get_foo"),
```

Use Django's [APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) in your base `Controller.py`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
class Controller(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def __init__(self):
        # Code
```

Then start your FooController class in `FooController.py` like so:

```
class FooController(Controller):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get_foo(self, request):
```